# Changing a link to a redirect page php

Tags: php

How do i change a url in a string example :

This is a link `<a href="http://google.com.au">http://google.com.au</a>`

To something like this

This a warning page link `<a href="./warn.php?link=http://google.com.au">http://google.com.au</a>`

EDIT:

What i'm trying to do is take a description entered by the end user, They might enter links in the description, i want to change all the links to make them GOTO a warning page, the warning page is `./warn.php?site=link`

The string might look like this

```
This is a awesome description <a href="google.com.au">Google</a> and this another link <a href="http://google.com.au/images">Google images</a>
```

Ok here's what i tried:

```
$descc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);

$descc = preg_replace('"\b(http://\S+)"', '<a href="./warn.php?site='.base64_encode(.'$1'.).'">$1</a>', $descc);
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, although im not sure if you are really refering to this, just let me know the case then ---

```
$mylink = "http://google.com.au";

This a warning page link <a href="./warn.php?link=<?php echo $mylink ?>">http://google.com.au</a>
```

**EDIT version 1.0**

Even it is on description box data you can fetch it via jquery or php like

```
$mylink = $_GET['desc_name_data'];
```

Please be more specific with the problem :)

**EDIT Version 1.1**

Check this and let me know then --

```
echo preg_replace('(<a href="http://\S+)', '<a href="./warn.php?site='.'google.com.au'.'">google.com.au', $descc);
```

Comment: Not what im looking for because the string is entered by a user into a description box, i want all the links in there to be changed to a warning page

Comment: That's not what i mean man, Say for example i enter This is a description `<a href="http://google.com.au">Link 1</a> And also this is <a href="http://google.com">Link 2</a>`

Comment: @ShaneEilia lol i know but... i think you need some time to frame your question, beter provide some code hint that what actually is going on..then we will surely help you in a better way :)

Comment: Ok here's what i tried `reg_replace('"\b(http://\S+)"', '<a href="./warn.php?site='.base64_encode(.'$1'.).'">$1</a>', $descc);` but i get an error and i know for sure that's not how you do it lol

Comment: @ShaneEilia just check this  ----    echo preg_replace('"\b(http://\S+)"', './warn.php?site='.'google.com.au'.'">google.com.au', $descc);

Comment: Tried that and it replaces all urls including the ones used in the image tags <img src='<a href="google.com.au">google.com.au</a>'> I just want the urls in the <a href""></a> tags changed

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for but instead of taking the user to Google can it take them to `warn.php?site=theurlentered`

Comment: Yeah surely u can but i think you need to set it bcoz link 1 is different from link 2 so u cant refer to 2 different pages simultaneously ;)

Comment: I don't get what you mean by set it ?

Comment: @ShaneEilia you can take them to "theurlentered" but i think its a separate issue to handle that URL from the descriptive data..and i think i provided you the solution what u ask ...waiting for the green tick ;) as accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at `preg_replace()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) may help.

```
<a href="./warn.php?link=<?php echo urlencode('http://google.com.au'); ?>">http://google.com.au</a>
```

If this isn't it, then please be a bit more specific with what you're trying to achieve and [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

EDIT:

Ok, you could try a [HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to extract the href from the link, then rewrite appropriately. This is likely to be more reliable that a regex.

You should still add urlencode if you're passing a url as a querystring.